# limit required number of checkboxes with php

Tags: php

I've been trying to find a solution to this for 3 days. Hopefully someone can help. The checkboxes need to limit the user to 2 or more selections. I know how to do this with javascript, but need to use PHP. Is this possible and if so, how?

```
            <label><input type="checkbox" value="Lemon" name='filling[]'  />Lemon</label></br>
        <label><input type="checkbox" value="Custard" name='filling[]'  />Custard</label></br>
        <label><input type="checkbox" value="Fudge" name='filling[]'  />Fudge</label></br>
        <label><input type="checkbox" value="Mocha" name='filling[]'  />Mocha</label></br>
        <label><input type="checkbox" value="Raspberry" name='filling[]'  />Raspberry</label></br>
        <label><input type="checkbox" value="Pineapple" name='filling[]'  />Pineapple</label>
```

Comment: php is a server-side language. it can **NOT** do anything to watch/limit what someone does in their browser. at most it can how many of the checkboxes were checked after the form is submitted to the server.

Comment: For such limits inside the browser you need JavaScript, a PHP error can be thrown on counting the entered fillings but it will be ridiculous validation and error..

Comment: Why do you need to use PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two responses gave me a good start. Got it to work with the following php.

```
if(empty($_POST['filling']) || count($_POST['filling']) < 2)
{
show_error("Please select at least two fillings");
}
$filling = check_input(implode("," , $_POST['filling']));
```

Answer (score 0):

You would do this by counting the number of selections

```
if(count($_POST['filling']) < 2){
    // throw error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are trying to process the submission of a form via PHP and want the user to select at least 2 checkboxes. When a form is submitted, checkboxes are only sent to the server IF they are checked. In your setup, you are using an array as a name. Simply check to see if the array is at least 2 in size.

```
$checkboxes = $_POST['filling'];

if( count($checkboxes) < 2 ) {
    die("You must select at least 2 checkboxes.");
}
```

Obviously there is a lot more you can do with this, but you get the gist.